# SQL UPDATE statement based on number of rows returned from SELECT subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with cols ID, and account type(int)

and I want to update account type to 3 for all rows, except one where given an ID there is more than one row with the same account type. so if I have

```
ID --- account_type
1  --- 2
1  --- 2
2  --- 1
2  --- 2
2  --- 3
```

I want to change one of the rows with id = 1 to have account type = 3 but leave the other one at 2 so I would like to return for the above example.

```
ID --- account_type
1  --- 2
1  --- 3
2  --- 1
2  --- 2
2  --- 3
```

I tried

```
UPDATE myTable
SET account_type = 3
WHERE 1 < (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY ID, account_type
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

but this updated every row in my db instead of just the one row with the duplicate account type so I know I did something wrong there. and this statement would set both rows with id=1 to have account_type =3 instead of just one row. How would I accomplish this?

EDIT:
I think I can fix the problem of only updating one row with:

```
UPDATE myTable p1
SET account_type = 3
WHERE 1 < (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM myTable p2
WHERE p1.primaryKey > p2.primaryKey
GROUP BY ID, account_type
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

but I'm still not sure why this updating every row in the db instead of the one with the duplicate account_type

Comment: @ErgestBasha oracle db

Comment: You have a missing `(`. Copy-and-paste problem?

Comment: @jarlh oh ya ty. I am copying over from my work machine so I mistyped

Answer (score 0):

So, we have table mytable:

```
| PrimaryKey  | ID  | account_type  |
| ----------- | --- | ------------- |
| 1           | 1   | 2             |
| 2           | 1   | 2             |
| 3           | 2   | 1             |
| 4           | 2   | 2             |
| 5           | 2   | 3             |
```

and I think, this is Your update:

```
update mytable
set account_type = 3 
where primarykey in (
  select min(primarykey) 
  from mytable
  group by id
)
and id not in (
  select id 
  from mytable
  where account_type = 3
);
```

this is the result:

```
| PrimaryKey  | ID  | account_type  |
| ----------- | --- | ------------- |
| 1           | 1   | 3             |
| 2           | 1   | 2             |
| 3           | 2   | 1             |
| 4           | 2   | 2             |
| 5           | 2   | 3             |
```